# Redirect To URL when a comment is approved in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hook

I am working on a custom post type, where the post content is updated with the comment content that is approved.

My code is:-

```
add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved', 'hgkb_update_post_content_on_comment_approval');
function hgkb_update_post_content_on_comment_approval($comment)
{
    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $comment = $comment->comment_content;
    $post_type=array('hgkb','hg-questions');
    if (in_array(get_post_type( $post_id ),$post_type))
    {
        $update_answer=wp_update_post( array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_content' => $comment) );
        if($update_answer)
        {
           //How to reload the page or redirect to another url?
        }
    }
}
```

Once the post content is updated, I want the content to be reflected in the content editor immediately or reload the page, so that the user can see the changes has been made.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using another hook. So the code becomes:-

```
add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved', 'hgkb_update_post_content_on_comment_approval');
function hgkb_update_post_content_on_comment_approval($comment)
{
    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $comment = $comment->comment_content;
    $post_type=array('hgkb','hg-questions');
    if (in_array(get_post_type( $post_id ),$post_type))
    {
        $update_answer=wp_update_post( array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_content' => $comment) );
        if($update_answer)
        {
           //How to reload the page or redirect to another url?
        }
    }
}
```

and then:-

```
add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'hgkb_reload_after_approval');
function hgkb_reload_after_approval()
{
    global $post;
    $post_type=array('hgkb','hg-questions');
    if (stristr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'post.php' ) !== false && is_object( $post ) && in_array(get_post_type( $post->ID ),$post_type) )
    {
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // Reload after 1 second when a comment approved
            jQuery(document).on('click', '.vim-a', function (e) {
            alert("Answer Updated!! The page will be reloaded after you click on OK. ");
            setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/post.php?post=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>&action=edit"
            }, 1000);
            });
            // END Reload after 1 second when a comment approved and Reload the Page when a comment approved
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```